# Could the "Echad" of Eloheinu ever become less than "Echad" like man & woman in [Genesis 2:24, Mark 12:25]?

Tags: genesis, mark, deuteronomy, attributes-of-god

When "Echad" is associated with the act of marriage in [Genesis 2:24], the אִ֔ישׁ Ish | "man" binds to אִשָּׁ֔ה Ishah | "woman" creating momentarily אֶחָֽד "Echad" one flesh. - Being mortals, the Ish and Ishah eventually separate in order to "be like Angels in heaven" [ Mark 12:25 ].

- Bereshit 2:24 "Therefore, a man shall leave his father and his mother, and cleave to his wife, and they shall become one flesh." ( עַל־כֵּן֙ יַֽעֲזָב־אִ֔ישׁ אֶת־אָבִ֖יו וְאֶת־אִמּ֑וֹ וְדָבַ֣ק בְּאִשְׁתּ֔וֹ וְהָי֖וּ לְבָשָׂ֥ר אֶחָֽד )
- Mark 12:25 [NASB] "For when they rise from the dead, they neither marry nor are given in marriage, but are like angels in heaven."

Yet [Deuteronomy 6:4] declares אֱלֹהֵ֖ינוּ Eloheinu "our God" is "Echad". - This "Echad" appears to be eternally sustained | never divided | always One.

- If Deuteronomy 6:4 is constant, Could the "Echad" of Eloheinu become less than "Echad" like man & woman in [Genesis 2:24, Mark 12:25]?

---

// To clarify : Based on the "Echad" of marriage dividing due to death (becoming lesser individuals like Angels), could the "Echad" of Eloheinu ever divide (becoming lesser individuals)? --

Comment: It’s worded a little confusing. What do you mean by “less than echad of a married couple”? How are you interpreting echad? One as in singular one identical to yachid? You think married couples are conjoined physically or united as one but two separate people?

Comment: Or are you asking if God can divide Himself into multiple persons? Which married couples are separate and distinct people to begin with, who after the resurrection no longer bond physically (intimately). Comparing God to married couples is the same as saying God is made up of two or more united persons

Comment: To clarify : We learn in Mark 12:25 that the "Echad" of marriage in Genesis 2:24 is not eternal. Based on Mark 12:25, when man or woman become less than "Echad" to become like an Angel, does the "Echad" of Eloheinu in deuteronomy 6:4 ever divide becoming less than a constant "Echad"?

Comment: When do married couples become LESS than echad? Either they are echad or they are not. Please give an example where a less than echad exists, I’m extending this to the person that up voted your comment. They seem to understand what you’re talking about.

Comment: Example [ Mark 12:19-25 ]

Comment: The combining doesn't make the meaning of the word echad to mean 2 or 3.. Show me a verse where echad means 2 or 3.. Echad means 1. You cannot twist it to make it to mean 3. Echad does not mean trinity.

Comment: @AlexBalilo I already showed you. *“A man shall leave his father and his mother and hold fast to his wife, and they shall become ECHAD flesh.”*
‭‭G2:24‬ ‭That’s TWO people UNITED as ONE *“And the Lord said, “Behold, they are ECHAD people...”*
‭‭G11:6‬ ‭that’s a multitude of people. *“And join them one to another into one stick, that they may become ECHAD in your hand.”*
‭‭Eze37:17‬ ‭two sticks UNITED as ONE. *“The hand of God was also on Judah to give them ECHAD heart to do what the king commanded by the word of the Lord.”*
‭‭2Chr30:12‬ ‭a UNITED as ONE HEART (I have more examples)

Comment: @AlexBalilo you’re getting it backwards. Echad means 2,3... UNITED as ONE, **not** ONE divided into 2,3...n. The two married couple don’t become one person. They are still distinct. A husband and a wife are two separate people. They are united in marriage but still individuals. The Father, Son and Holy Spirit are UNITED as God but still separate and distinct persons.

Comment: How is Mark 12:19-25 an example of an echad becoming less than. It’s saying that the man and the woman were echad in marriage. She was echad in marriage to all seven men. BUT at the resurrection there is no more marriage. So they will no longer be echad AT ALL. Because they won’t unite as one in that way ever again. Please explain your definition of echad @חִידָה

Comment: Correct. - Based on the "Echad" of marriage dividing due to death (becoming lesser individuals like Angels), could the "Echad" of Eloheinu ever divide (becoming lesser individuals).

Comment: Could GOD decide to separate into Father, Son and Holy Spirit and still be GOD? I don’t know I know the answer to that. I know God is Father, Son and Holy Spirit united as one or echad. If they decided to break pact, I’m not sure what God would “look” like. Finally understand your question +1

Comment: Can you please provide a lexicon that shows the meaning of echad to be 3 instead of the number 1?

Comment: I think the fact that YHWH is eternal and immutable suggests that "God is" and God will always be echad!

Comment: @AlexBalilo - the best is what has already been quoted - Gen 2:24 - "the two shall be one".  See also Matt 13:13,Jer 5:21 and Isa 6:9-10.

Comment: @Dottard. So you say echad =2? Lexicon proving that please? None of the verses you provide say that God is a trinity., Compare that to Jesus' plain statement in John 17:3 and 14:28.If you believe Jesus is God, why do you not believe Jesus when he said that the Father is the only true God? Are there plain and unequivocal statements similar to John 17:3 in the bible that say God is a trinity?

Comment: @AlexBalilo - please do NOT put words in my mouth.  Echad means one - no question but that is the point - the text in Gen 2:24 clearly says that the act of marriage make two sperate people "exhad".  Now Alex - how would YOU translate that text?

Comment: @Dottard. The combining of Adam and Eve as one flesh does not change the meaning of echad which is the cardinal number 1 in counting. This verse does not prove that God is a trinity, but you are twisting the meaning of echad to imply that is a "compound one" so that in verses where the phrase “one God” appears, you can suggest that the word “one” imparts some sort of plurality to the word God.. Do you, because of this verse, believe there are actually two Gods when you read verses that contain the words "one God" " the only true God"? –